# RHEL - permanently unmask all sub-folders and files

Tags: permissions, rhel

I'm new to RHEL, and I'm having issues unmasking a collections of directories.

I have a folder where content will be generated content from a python script.  The subfolders will exists for a period of time, then get deleted.  The folders were originally masked with one user being able to read/write to them, but recently we needed to allow anyone to access these folders.  I ran the unmask command on the folder with the -R (recursive option) to unmask all subfolders and files. It appeared to work until new content was generated and BAM same problem, the folders and files were masked.

How do I permanently unmask all sub-folders and files for a folder?  I need these files to be accessible to everyone with create/read/write access.

Answer (score 1):

The process that's creating the files is the issue. This process/program is running with a given `umask` such that when it creates files the newly created files will be created with a particular `umask`. You essentially have 3 options:

1. Modify processes' umask

   Depending on what the process is (web server) this is probably not what you want to do.
2. Add a group

   The more friendly way to do this would be to create a Unix group (web-data), again if it's web server related content that everyone needs access to. Then change the top level group of the directories in question, so that they're owned/accessible by members of group web-data.

   Then run commands similar to these to make the directory's group web-data, and to force the group to be sticky, so that any new files/folders created will be made with this group as their default.

   ```
   $ chgrp web-data /path/to/dir
   $ find /path/to/dir -type d -exec chmod g+xs {} +
   ```

   Finally add the web server user (apache) to this group along with others that need access to this directory.
3. use access control lists (ACLs)

   You can use the tools `setfacl` and `getfacl` to manipulate ACLs on a given directory or file.

   #### Example

   As root:

   ```
   $ mkdir somedir
   $ getfacl somedir
   # file: somedir
   # owner: root
   # group: root
   user::rwx
   group::r-x
   other::r-x
   ```

   Now add access for user `sam` to the directory.

   ```
   $ setfacl -Rm u:sam:r-x,d:sam:r-x somedir
   getfacl somedir/
   # file: somedir
   # owner: root
   # group: root
   user::rwx
   user:sam:r-x
   group::r-x
   mask::r-x
   other::r-x
   default:user::rwx
   default:user:sam:r-x
   default:group::r-x
   default:mask::r-x
   default:other::r-x
   ```

   Now any subsequent directories and/or files that get created will have their directories set so that user `sam` can access them:

   ```
   $ mkdir anotherdir
   $ echo "hello world" > anotherfile
   ```

   Confirm the permissions:

   ```
   $ getfacl another*
   # file: anotherdir
   # owner: root
   # group: root
   user::rwx
   user:sam:r-x
   group::r-x
   mask::r-x
   other::r-x
   default:user::rwx
   default:user:sam:r-x
   default:group::r-x
   default:mask::r-x
   default:other::r-x

   # file: anotherfile
   # owner: root
   # group: root
   user::rw-
   user:sam:r-x            #effective:r--
   group::r-x          #effective:r--
   mask::r--
   other::r--
   ```

   Now as user `sam`:

   ```
   $ more anotherfile 
   hello world
   ```

   If another user needs similar access, simply rerun the `setfacl` command using that user's username in place of `sam`.

   The above approach could be modified so that instead of a single user being granted access, a group of users could be granted access instead.

#### References

- [setfacl man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html)
- [Access Control Lists](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists)
- [How does one get setfacl to set ACL permissions recursively on Ubuntu 9.04 server edition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2736/how-does-one-get-setfacl-to-set-acl-permissions-recursively-on-ubuntu-9-04-serve)

Comment: Thank you, Can you make option 3, so any user can rwx on the folder?

Comment: @josh1234 - yes just change the `r-x` in the `setfacl` so that they're `rwx`.

Comment: I did setfacl -Rm d:o:rwx <folder>, but I get operation not supported.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @josh1234 - as root or using `sudo`? You need permissions to do this activity on the directory. What RHEL is this?